# how to implement google consumer surveys

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-surveys

I have implemented google consumer survey in my local web server using google code which is provided google(that is only js file)
like

```
<script async="" defer="" src="//survey.g.doubleclick.net/async_survey?site=3zpezx32utlew"></script>
```

but nothing work
can any bode suggest how it works and how to implement

Comment: Please explain what this question has to do with the tags php and google-app-engine, or please add more relevant tags such as javascript, survey and consumer to attract the attention of more people who might answer it.

Comment: If you can't get GCS working, Survata offers a [similar product](http://survata.com/publisher-network).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't forget you also need to click "Activate" to activate your survey. Also, put your script tag right before you close you head tag

```
...
<script async="" defer="" src="//survey.g.doubleclick.net/async_survey?site=3zpezx32utlew"></script></head>
```